# How to retrieve pack list with Shippingbo API?

Tags: api

We need to retrieve pack list throught the api.

A pack is a composition of multiple products, available in shippingbo backoffice in menu Products / Packs.

It is possible to get a product list :
https://app.shippingbo.com/products

It is possible to get product data or a pack data with same url :
[https://app.shippingbo.com/products/{product_id}](https://app.shippingbo.com/products/%7Bproduct_id%7D)
[https://app.shippingbo.com/products/{pack_id}](https://app.shippingbo.com/products/%7Bpack_id%7D)

But we can find a way to get a way to get a list of packs which should be for example :
https://app.shippingbo.com/packs

Or is there a way to get packs throught the product list with a specific parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `is_pack` parameter to filter the list and get packs:

```bash
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://app.shippingbo.com/products?is_pack=true' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'X-API-TOKEN: ' \
  --header 'X-API-USER: ' \
  --header 'X-API-USER-ID: ' \
  --header 'X-API-VERSION: '
```